# Web Server Session-Based Caching Security Issue?

Tags: caching, iis-7

I am wondering if what I'm doing is a good practice. Please advise. Thanks.

My web application server caches generated chart images for users to enhance performance.
The images are stored in session-based folders, where the folder name is generated.
Let's say user1 plotted a chart and is cached on the server here:
    webapp\sessionFolder\aklfq13d10jd10\image.jpg

I disabled IIS7 directory browsing.
But I find that other users of the system, can access the image too, if they input the full url. But they're not supposed to see it as it is cached for user1.

How can I avoid such illegal accesses? Or is there a better practice to implement such web caching?

Thank you!
Kyeo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to cache images in a directory that is not accessible to the client (for example, a subdirectory of App_Data), then have a handler that streams the contents of files from this directory to authorized users.

If the files are specific to a user, you could for example store the images in folder names derived from the username:

```
App_Data\TempImages\User1
App_Data\TempImages\User2
```

Then the handler that streams the content will only stream files for the current logged on user, something like (modulo a bit of error handling):

```
string path = Path.Combine(
           AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
           "App_Data\TempImages", 
           HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, 
           Request.QueryString["imageFileName"]);

... stream image at path if it exists ...
```

You could use the sessionId as an identifier instead of the username, but in this case the cached data will become inaccessible whenever the session times out.

Comment: Thank you @Joe. Do you have reading references on such approach? I'd like to find out more on the implementation details. Can you kindly share them?

Comment: @Kyeo1983 - the linked article has info on creating a handler to stream an image.  It gets the image from the database: in your case you'll be reading it from a file on disk: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingSessionStateInHttpHandlersASHXFiles.aspx